# Rearrange DatePicker from mm-dd-yyyy to yyyy-mm-dd

Tags: android, datepicker

I have a custom datepicker in the format MM-DD-YYYY. I made it custom because I need the month field as numbers. Now, I want it to arrange the fields into YYYY-MM-DD format but I don't know how. Here is the constructor of my custome datepicker:

```
import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Build;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.widget.DatePicker;
import android.widget.NumberPicker;

import java.lang.reflect.Field;

public class MyDatePicker extends DatePicker {
    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
    public MyDatePicker(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        Field[] fields = DatePicker.class.getDeclaredFields();
        try {
            String[] s = new String[] {"01","02","03","04","05","06","07","08","09","10","11","12"};
            for (Field field : fields) {
                field.setAccessible(true);
                if (TextUtils.equals(field.getName(), "mMonthSpinner")) {
                    NumberPicker monthPicker = (NumberPicker) field.get(this);
                    monthPicker.setDisplayedValues(s);
                }
                if (TextUtils.equals(field.getName(), "mShortMonths")) {
                    field.set(this, s);
                }

            }
        }

        catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had exactly the same problem (numbers for months, the order of "fields" and hiding the day picker in some situations). Wrote my own date picker at the end.
The problem is that the standard android datepicker arranges the NumberSpinners according to the locale set in the device. There's a method for that called reorderPickers. Have a look there.

Comment: this is for a korean company, they wanted it to be formatted that way.. would android rearrange it?

Comment: I believe it will rearrange if you change the locale in your android OS. Other than that it's either extending the datepicker somehow or writing your own.

Comment: yeah, it works! I tried changing my language and the fields were arranged :) thanks!

Comment: Keep in mind that if other users will have different settings they'll see the date fields sorted other way. Take care!